# Can a calendar popup be added to a list's date filter instead of a list of text choices?

Tags: list, list-view, calendar, filter

How would I replace the OOTB list date filter dropdown to be a calendar view instead?

JQuery/Javascript solutions are feasible for me if it is indeed possible.

[image]

So far looking at the page tags upon opening the filter, I can infer the class name as:

"ms-MenuUIPopupBody ms-MenuUIPopupScreen"

with the following classes underneath it, if that helps at all

"ms-MenuUIPopupInner", "ms-MenuUI", "ms-MenuUIUL"

It's not clear yet how and what I would replace those with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DatePicker in the jQueryUI - http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

However, I think this would replace the column header completely so you would lose the option to sort.

What about adding a separate date filter on the page?